# Python/Django exclude running tests in subdirectory

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to run all tests in a Python project from a particular directory but need to exclude some test from a subdirectory.

Would like input into how to exclude tests from a subdirectory.

```
home/
   --tests/
      --views/
          --/viewtest1.py
      --models/
          --/modeltest1.py
      --test1.py
```

I basically want to run everything under home except anything in tests/view.

#This will execute all tests under home but would include views tests.

```
./manage.py test home
```

EXCLUDE_DIRS from python is only ignoring top level directories and not a subdirectory. So this statement doesn't work.

```
EXCLUDE_DIRS=views ./manage.py test home
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to run the test from sub dir you should follow some rules:
your test file should follow pattern *`test_{test-name}.py`*
in sub dir you must add a *`__init__.py`* file like this:

```
home/
   --tests/
      --views/
          __init__.py
          --/viewtest1.py
      --models/
          __init__.py
          --/modeltest1.py
      __init__.py
      --test1.py
```

note:
you can add test files in your *`__init__.py`* like this

*tests/models/`__init__.py`*

```
from test_models import *
# the file modeltest1.py renamed to test_models.py
```

Comment: I'm not trying to run tests from a particular subdirectory. Rather exclude tests from a subdirectory.